# IIS Splash Page showing instead of SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis, alternate-access-mapping

I'm having issues connecting to our sharepoint site using our server name. When we enter in our server name it is showing an IIS splash page with a clickable image that redirects to the microsoft iis site.

Our SharePoint site url I'm trying to access is  (http://servername). When i look at the root folder for the default site (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) thats where the IIS page is showing from.

Here are my Alternate Access Mapping Settings

```
Internal URL                Public URL                   Zone
http://servername           http://servername            Default
https://externalsite.com    https://externalsite.com     Internet
```

This is a multi-tier server farm with only 2 servers in the farm. How do i get my http://servername to work again and show my sharepoint site? The SharePoint site is on port 80 and I'm not entirely show what changes I made for this to happen...

Thank you so much

Comment: I've seen this before, and it was because there is no homepage redirection or somehow the redirection to the homepage doesn't work either through F5 or URL rewriting.

Comment: When i use the http:// redirect its showing the external url... is possible to still have http://servername showing?

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to access it by http://servername , you can STOP / delete the Default Web Site on IIS. Make sure your SharePoint Web Application is started as well.

Comment: Is it best practice to just do a http redirect? or do most people use the internal server name to access it.